# Python insert to sql server from multiple csv

Tags: python, python-3.x

Newbie here, trying to import from multiple csv to sql server, the code did run but no data inserted into sql database.
Attached is my code. Maybe the error is lie on the loop.

Please help.

```
import csv
import pyodbc as p
import os

# Database Connection Info
server = "cld-077\eform"
database = "E-form"
username = "wsmeform"
password = "M1loA1s!"
connStr = (
'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};SERVER=' + server + ';DATABASE=' + database + ';UID=' + username + ';PWD=' + password)

# Open connection to SQL Server Table
conn = p.connect(connStr)

# Get cursor
cursor = conn.cursor()

# Assign path to Excel files
print("Inserting!")

folder_to_import = 'C:/Users/ck.law/Desktop/VBFU_NOV/'

print("path")

l_files_to_import = os.listdir(folder_to_import)
print("inside loop")
for file_to_import in l_files_to_import:
    if file_to_import.endswith('.csv'):

        csv_files = os.path.join(folder_to_import, file_to_import)
        csv_data = csv.reader(csv_files)
        for row in csv_data:
            if len(row) >= 19:
                cursor.execute(
                    "INSERT INTO VesselBFUData(ShortCode,DocDT,PostDT,DocNo,LineItm,GlCode,ExpType,InvRef,VBaseCurrcy,VBaseAmt,DocCurrcy,DocAmt,VendorCode,Description,InvFilePath,InvCreateDT,InvAppvDT,InvArriDT,PoRef)" " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
                    row)
                print("Loop!")

cursor.close()

conn.commit()

conn.close()

print("Script has successfully run!")
```

Comment: What error do you get? and also in query you can do values("%s, %s" % rows) instead of ?.

Comment: Actually no error, but just it doesnt insert the data from csv to SQL server.

Comment: Issue resolved. The code doesnt have the open csv function, after adding in, everything is fine.